# How to fix this bad_lib error in the crypto module?

Tags: erlang

When I try to run `crypto:start()` from my erlang shell this error is thrown

> ** exception error: undefined function crypto:start/0
>   2> 
>   =ERROR REPORT==== 29-May-2014::00:24:54 ===
>   Unable to load crypto library. Failed with error:
>   "bad_lib, Library version (2.6) not compatible (with 2.4)."
>   OpenSSL might not be installed on this system.
>
> =ERROR REPORT==== 29-May-2014::00:24:54 ===
>
> The on_load function for module crypto returned {error,
>                                                    {bad_lib,
>                                                     "Library version (2.6) not compatible (with 2.4)."}}

I can see that the error clearly states that the two crypto library versions are incompatible but how do I fix this issue. Specifically how do I install 2.4 version of the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I updated to the latest version of erlang and it got crypto working. I think that 2.6 version of library got in when I had previously tried 17 (I had to remove it because couchdb did not support it).  And the crypto 2.6 library must have stuck.

Comment: i also faced the same issue. had installed multiple versions 17, 20, r16b02 so removed the folder `/usr/local/lib/erlang` and did a `make install` again. It worked.